# spacing out divs on $(window).resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to horizontally space a variable number of ".wrapper" divs evenly inside of an ".elements" div.

.wrapper is `position: relative` and `float: left`

.elements is `position: absolute`

The function I am using to space the ".wrapper" divs is as follows:

```
$(window).resize(function() { //on resize we...
    x = $('.elements').width(); //new width means new x
    y = Math.floor(x / pane); //new x means new y
    marginSize = (x - (pane * y)) / (2 * y); //set margineSize with new params
    $('.wrapper').css({
        'margin-left': marginSize,
        //change left margin on resize
    });
});
```

This should space the .wrapper divs evenly. But only in very special circumstances will they be spaced evenly within the .elements wrapper div. Most of the time they seem shifted to the left.

What I have:

-several divs being spread evenly from each other
-divs getting as close as a pixel (or closer?) away from each other

What I want:

-Several divs being spread evenly from each other to fit evenly within another div
-divs remaining a minimum distance of 25px from each other

Here is a [working jsfiddle version](http://jsfiddle.net/aL3fy/12/) of what I am talking about.  Resize the output to see what I mean.

I hope my explanation makes sense.  If any clarification or additions are needed please let me know. (this is my first question here...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I splitted the margin into left and right, and centered the holding container (#holder) to be sure that there is always an equal space between the containers.

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    x=$('.elements').width();
    y=Math.floor(x/pane);
    marginSize=(x-(pane*y))/(2*y);
    $('#holder').css({width:(pane*y)+(marginSize*y)});
    $('.wrapper').css({
        'margin-right':marginSize/2,
        'margin-left':marginSize/2
    });
});
```

You'll find my solution here: http://jsfiddle.net/axelmichel/jnmWE/.
 
Additionally I emulate the minimum space of 25px / 50px by adding borders to containers. In case you have a different background where you can't use borders, you could work with a nested div which contains the minimum space.

Comment: This was actually the logic I was using in my first draft. Take a look at your jsfiddle page and try resizing the page so that you are going between having one column and two columns. I realized that when you resize using this logic, there is a lot of flickering of the relocating divs because the margin-right and margin-left are fighting over whether or not the divs should relocate.  I'd almost prefer to have a little extra space on the right than have the divs flickering. but if there were a way to remove the flickering, this response has the best even spacing.

Comment: The flickering effect seems to be browser / client dependent, I don't have this in chrome. Anyway here is a solution with only margin-left, to stay centered I added another wrapping container with a dynamic negative margin: http://jsfiddle.net/axelmichel/pDbLq/

Comment: Thank you so much!
About the first one: I see the flicker in firefox, but when I looked at it just now in chrome there was no flicker. I wonder why that happens...

Comment: Is there any way to do it without the borders?  This solves my problem, but visually I would like to be able to do it without borders.

Comment: You could use another nested div in each wrapper to do so, the wrapper itself has the padding left/right with your minimum space, all other style rules go to the nesting container. Have a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/axelmichel/M7qE3/

Answer (score 1):

Add 25 to your marginSize:

```
marginSize=(x-(pane*y))/(2*y)+25; //Sets marginSize
```

Is it that what you want?

http://jsfiddle.net/muffls/thZgT/

Comment: It's really close! Sorry to be nit-picky, but the elements are still not always spaced evenly. When the elements are about to shift down there is a lot more room on the far right where the new element will move. If this is the best I can do, then so be it, but if it is possible to always have them spaced evenly I would prefer that.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you assign a minimum width in px to ".elements" div?

Comment: Not quite an answer to my question, but a really great suggestion that I will definitely use.  Thank you!